# Unexpected url in case of signature base string of woocommerce api through okhttp client

Tags: java, android, okhttp, woocommerce-rest-api

The url to generate signature is

```
GET&http%3A%2F%2Fprojectrepo.net%2Fscoop%2Fwp-json%2Fwc%2Fv2%2Forders&oauth_consumer_key%3Dck_2f53925cb6d2c8f96407f09f67f5f118d01ed80e%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
```

the string without utf encoding is

`GET&http://----.net/----/wp-json/wc/v2/orders&oauth_consumer_key=----&oauth_signature_method=----`

The problem is that when this url is passed through okhttp client  to generate signature,the "unexpected url" error is shown on the log.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(signatureBaseString)
                    .build();
Response response = null;
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

What is wrong? Can't okhttp client be used to generate signature as the url is utf encoded which is required to generate signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

The code for generating signature in android is given as follows

```
Mac mac = null;
mac = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA1");
String secret = oauthConsumerSecretKeyStringValue+"&";
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("utf-8"), "HMAC-SHA1"));
signature = Base64.encodeToString(mac.doFinal(signatureBaseString.getBytes("utf-8")), 0).trim();
```

The oauthConsumerSecretKeyStringValue variable has the consumer secret key.

The signature base string is the string having all the oauth parameters beside the oauth_signature.This string is used to generate the signature.

Now the "GET&" characters are mandatory at the time of signature generation.But when the data is posted it should post at the url devoid of this "GET&" characters.

Everyone thanks for your time.

Comment: followed same approach but getting singnature_invalid exception